# Checkbox and AlerDialog

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have to bring up a dialog in java alert to inform the user if he wants to remove the ads have to buy the paid version of the app ... I did two java files .. and another one called dialogue from which recall the above file and other elements defined in a layout xml ... the problem is that if I put new Dialog (this) gives me error ... instead if currently run the app by clicking on the checkbox crashes the app.The checkbox following the crash has checked that there should be ... the checkbox **must not be** checkable.

```
package com.X.XX.XXX;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;

public class Dialogo {

    public static final int BUY = 1000;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public void mostra(int Id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(Id)
        {
        case BUY:
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setMessage("TEXT ");
            builder.setNegativeButton("CLOSE", null);
            builder.setPositiveButton("BUY", null);
            break;
        }
        builder.create().show();
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.X.XX;

import com.X.XX.XXX.Dialog;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{

    CheckBoxPreference no_ads;
    Dialogo dialogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        dialogo = new Dialogo(); 

        no_ads = (CheckBoxPreference) this.findPreference("no_ads");
        no_ads.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialogo.mostra(Dialogo.BUY);
                ((CheckBoxPreference)preference).setChecked(false);
                return false;
            }});

    }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: this is the logcat, sorry... https://www.dropbox.com/s/53tbfexplqqe36k/crash.txt

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your builder variable before using it.
So make sure to pass context as well to your function, first declare it like this:

```
public void mostra(Context context, int Id) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

And then call it like this:

```
dialogo.mostra(Settings.this, Dialogo.BUY);
```

Complete working example:

```
package com.X.XX.XXX;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;

public class Dialogo {
    public static final int BUY = 1000;

    public void mostra(Context context, int Id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(Id)
        {
        case BUY:
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setMessage("TEXT ");
            builder.setNegativeButton("CLOSE", null);
            builder.setPositiveButton("BUY", null);
            break;
        }
        builder.create().show();
    }
}


package com.X.XX;
import com.X.XX.XXX.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{
    CheckBoxPreference no_ads;
    Dialogo dialogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        dialogo = new Dialogo(); 

        no_ads = (CheckBoxPreference) this.findPreference("no_ads");
        no_ads.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialogo.mostra(Settings.this, Dialogo.BUY);
                ((CheckBoxPreference)preference).setChecked(false);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Continues to give me error here   dialogo.mostra(PreferenceActivity.this, Dialogo.BUY); say " No enclosing instance of the type preference activity is accessible in scope " I put in the first java file that portion of the code you posted and in the second the call. I'm going crazy :-(

Comment: I've edited my answer, the second part specifically -- try now.

Comment: very good ... thank you friend ... in that row no longer reports error but now there is an errore here dialogo.mostra (Dialogo.BUY); :-S

Comment: You changed the signature of mostra method, you must pass Context everytime you call it, hence dialogo.mostra(Dialogo.BUY) is invalid.

Comment: excuse me, I have tried to pass the context as you told me but I get an error ... I put dialogo.mostra (Context) in addition to this I have tried many other combinations but I always get errors ... I've got bumped my head for more than ten minutes .. I hope you can help me :-) Thanks